# Can't find the libluajava.so

Tags: java, android, sdk, lua

I'm using the YOUKU SDK in my Android project, and to my Beta users, their app will crash becasuse of the libluajava.so, like this:

[image]

So I google the libluajava.so and download it, put it in the following folders.

// I don't put it in the armeabi folder or the armeabi-v7a folder because the project will say something like there are some duplicate files

[image]

But the problem still unsolved, the app still crash because something like that:

[image]

But I can't find the 64-bit file on the web, so how can I fix this?

Comment: Are you using the NDK tools?

Comment: I have not used the NDK tools now. Can the NDK tools convert the .so to 64-bit version?

Comment: It is always better to build .so file from the available lib files rather than copy pasting the .so. And the best way to build .so is using NDK tools

Answer (score 0):

To build .so, you can use this procedure -

Add android ndk tools to a location where your android sdk is present.

Now in your eclipse project, create a jni folder with all your .c and .h files and also your Android.mk file.

Now in your eclipse, goto Run -> External Tools -> External Tools Configuration. For location, press "Browse File System" and choose the "ndk-build" location(which you have put in android sdk folder) For Working Directory, press "Browse Workspace" and choose your eclipse project and your jni folder. For example like this - ${workspace_loc:/yourproject/jni}

Press Apply and then press Run. You have your .so in libs folder of your eclipse project.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! :) But the libluajava.so is not developed by me. So I need to find the available lib files on the internet, then use the NDK tools to convert these file to 64-bit .so and 32-bit .so?

Comment: Yes the 32 bit or 64 bit will be taken care by the NDK tools. You dont need to worry :)